# Loop não está caminhando, não sai da primeira posição

Tags: r, loop, for

```
f3 <- function(n)  {
  dados <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  matrizB <- matrix(0,2, n)
  for (i in 1:length(dados)) {
    s <- 1
    if (i <= 0.2) {
      matrizB[1,] <- 1
      matrizB[2,] <- 0.2
    }
    if (i > 0.2 | i<=0.7) {
      matrizB[1,] <- 2
      matrizB[2,] <- 0.5
    }
    else {
      matrizB[1,] <- 3
      matrizB[2,] <- 0.3
      s <- s + 1
    }
  return(matrizB)
  }
}

f3(3) # o loop não está caminhando, não sai da primeira posição
```

O exercício era: Considere a variável aleatória Y com a seguinte distribuição de probabilidade:

```
     y 1   2   3
P(Y=y) 0,2 0,5 0,3
```

É possível gerar um valor desta distribuição de probabilidade inicialmente gerando um valor X de uma distribuição Uniforme(0,1). Se X ≤ 0, 2 então Y = 1, se 0, 2 < X ≤ 0, 7 então Y = 2, se X > 0, 7 então Y = 3. a) Usando for e gerando valores da distribuição Uniforme(0,1), faça uma função para gerar uma amostra de tamanho n (único argumento da função) da distribuição de probabilidade de Y.

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma solução em R base sem ciclos `for`. Utiliza `cumsum` e `findInterval` para determinar os valores de `y`.

```
f3 <- function(n, fmp){
  prob_acum <- cumsum(fmp)
  p <- runif(n)
  findInterval(p, c(0, prob_acum), rightmost.closed = TRUE, all.inside = TRUE)
}

set.seed(2021)

FMP <- c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3)  # A função massa de probabilidade
x <- f3(1e6, FMP)        # teste com n = 1e6

tbl <- table(x)          # verificar se as proporções
                         # correspondem às probabilidades
tbl/sum(tbl)
#x
#       1        2        3 
#0.199352 0.500465 0.300183
```

Answer (score 0):

Você esta pedindo para retornar matriz B toda vez que o laço for executado, logo na primeira vez que o laço rodar já sairá do laço. Se o seu objetivo é fazer com que a função f retorne algo, retire o  `return(matrizB)` de dentro do for.
Outro ponto, tente fazer testes nos seus valores, assim você parende a debugar, como por exemplo verificar que o tamanho do dados, fazendo um `print(length(dados))`. (Se sua linguagem for js, use console.log)